# Which notable developments/products were announced during RootsTech 2015?

Tags: data-storage, rootstech

How can I find out about notable technical developments and products that were announced during RootsTech 2015?

Were there any major software releases, progress regarding GEDCOM successors, or new databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the post-conference reports appear, one can review the technical content of RootsTech 2015 by going to the [conference schedule](https://rootstech.org/schedule?lang=eng) and filtering for the "Innovator Summit" track.

The handouts for the presentations and workshops are available for download: see the [2015 Class Syllabus](https://rootstech.org/About/syllabus?lang=eng) (use the Class Numbers from the schedule to find the presentation you are interested in).

A few presentations that were streamed live are in the [2015 Video Archive](https://rootstech.org/video/4050134760001), including the [Innovator Challenge](https://rootstech.org/video/4050134760001).

Another way to review the new tech that was announced via RootsTech is to look at the [submissions page for the Innovator Challenge](http://rootstech.challengepost.com/submissions).

The submission which met my criteria for "most notable development" was the 2nd-place [ArgusSearch](http://challengepost.com/software/argussearch), a search engine for **handwritten documents** which combines the power of a search engine with handwriting recognition.

An archive or other organization with digital images of handwritten documents could partner with ArgusSearch and have the content instantly searchable, with no need to wait for indexers.

Apart from that, I agree with [Tamura Jones](https://twitter.com/TamuraJones), who tweeted about the lamentable lack of innovation during the Innovator Challenge:

> #rootstech All four presentations done, and still waiting for something innovative...

And:

> #rootstech "Innovation". You keep using that word. I don't think it means what you think it means.

Many of the projects were "me too" companies, offering variations on products and services which were already available.

One barrier to real innovation may be the current market conditions, in which companies are expected to give away the product for free, with a paid or "pro" option.

I have marked this post as 'community wiki' so everyone can edit and add links to blog posts and other reports below the line.

---

- James Tanner, *Genealogy's Star*:  [Some Thoughts on Genealogical Startups](http://genealogysstar.blogspot.com/2015/02/some-thoughts-on-genealogical-startups.html) posted Wednesday, February 18, 2015